# Após mover um post para a lixeira, os valores dos metabox somem quando eu restauro o post

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Eu tenho um tema do wordpress, onde nos posts eu tenho alguns metabox personalizados.

Ao mover o post para a lixeira e recupera-lo novamente, ele não retorna com os valores dos metabox preenchidos

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está passando pelo mesmo problema descrito [nessa questão](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32010/custom-field-values-deleted-when-trashing-custom-post-type) (em Inglês).

Provavelmente é um *bug* no tema causado porque a função `save_post` é chamada sem os dados do *post* quando o artigo é enviado para a lixeira.

Como descrito no link acima, a solução é acrescentar uma condição na função de salvamento para não salvar os meta-dados nesse caso.

Exemplo extraído do link, que você deverá adaptar no seu tema:

```php
function wpg_save_testimonial_author($post_id) {
  global $post;
  if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['testimonial_author_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__).$post->ID)) {
    return $post->ID;
  }
  if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return $post_id;
  }
  if(defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
    return;
  }
  if(!current_user_can('edit_post')) {
    return $post->ID;
  }
  if($post->post_type == 'revision') {
    return;
  }
  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'testimonial_author_name', $_POST['testimonial_author_name']);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'testimonial_author_link', $_POST['testimonial_author_link']);
}
add_action('save_post', 'wpg_save_testimonial_author');
```